# how to change the treenode rect size?

Tags: delphi

i want my tree view shown as folows.[image]

this is the code i am using.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TreeView1.FullExpand
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);

const
  _Right = 100;
  _Left = 50;

var
  R : TRect;

begin

 if Node.Level = 0 then
 begin

  R := Node.DisplayRect(true);

  R.Right := R.Right + _Right;
  R.Left := R.Left + _Left;

  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(R);

 end;

end;
```

the problem is i can extend the R.right but cannot  extend the R.left...

Comment: You mean that you want to indent your node captions (but only captions) ?

Comment: depending on what you want to reach you might set `Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;` after FillRect, or `DefaultDraw:=false` and paint anything on your own.

Comment: yes i want to indent node captions

Comment: @bummi, but you have to make some extra space for the node display rectangle. And that's what the control doesn't support directly, I think. ([`node height you can set`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21001812/960757), but I couldn't find a way to adjust node width, so I would probably append a few spaces to the item caption; I know, it's ugly).

Comment: I would do this using "OwnerDraw" settings. That allows this and a lot more.

Comment: @TLama I'm not sure what he is really looking for LU RD 's solution would cover one version, from what is shown in Azzi's image it differs and `Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;` after FillRect would be enough , maybe some adjustment for longer Text ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do the drawing in the`OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` event, there are more options.

This does it for me (filtering out the cdPostPaint Stage):

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
  var PaintImages, DefaultDraw: Boolean);
const
  _Right = 100;
  _Left = 50;
var
  R : TRect;
begin
 if (Node.Level = 0) and (stage = cdPostPaint) then
 begin

  R := Node.DisplayRect(true);
  R.Right := R.Right + 2; 
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(R); // Just clear default text area

  R.Right := R.Right + _Right;
  R.Left := R.Left + _Left;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(R);
  {- Make sure writing text with transparent background }
  SetBkMode( Sender.Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT );
  Sender.Canvas.TextOut(R.Left,R.Top,Node.Text);
  PaintImages := true;
  DefaultDraw := false;
 end;    
end;
```

[image]